# DIV animation and color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to simulate TCP packet transmission, and hopefully I've made much progress. But now I want to fix two minor issues, that I need help with:

1- I want to highlight the corresponding cell in the table on the bottom of the page as yellow when the packet is being sent, and later when its ack is received, change the color to green.

2- The `speed` variable got from the input does not work!!

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/j26Qc/108/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var count = 0;
    var items = 0;
    var packetNumber = 0;
    var speed = 0;
    var ssth= $("#ssth").val();
    var window_left=0;

   for(var i=1;i<=32;i++){
$('#table').append("<div class='inline' id='"+i+"'>"+i+"</div>");
    }
        document.getElementById(1).style.width=22;

    $("button").click(function () {
        if (count < ssth) {
            if(items==0)
                items=1;
            else
            items = items * 2;      
            count++;
        } else {
            items = items + 1;
        }

        window_left+=20;
        window_width=items*20;

        document.getElementById("window").style.left= window_left+"px";
        document.getElementById("window").style.width=window_width+"px";

        speed = $("#speed").val();
        createDivs(items);
        animateDivs();
    });

    function createDivs(divs) {
        packetNumber = 1;
        var left = 60;
        for (var i = 0; i < divs; i++) {
            var div = $("<div class='t'></div>");
            div.appendTo(".packets");
            $("<font class='span'>" + packetNumber + "</font>").appendTo(div);
            packetNumber++;
            div.css({
                left: left
               /* opacity: 0*/
            }).fadeOut(0);

            //div.hide();
            //left += 20;
        }
    }

    function animateDivs() {
        $(".t").each(function (index) {  // added the index parameter
            var packet = $(this);


            packet
                .delay(index * 200)
                .fadeIn(200)
                .animate({left: '+=230px'}, speed)
                .animate({left: '+=230px'}, speed)
                .fadeOut(200, function () {
                    packet
                        .css({
                            top: '+=20px', 
                            backgroundColor: "#f09090"
                        })    
                        .text('a' + packet.text());
                 })                
                .delay(1000)
                .fadeIn(200)
                .animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed)
                .animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed)
                .fadeOut(200, function () {
                    packet
                        .css({
                            top: '-=20px',
                            backgroundColor: "#90f090"
                        });
                });

        }).promise().done(function(){
        $(".packets").empty();});

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1.

When it comes to coloring it is best to add an extra variable holding the count of items. A quick and dirty way, without adding a variable and instead using `window_left / 20`, would be in `animateDivs()`:

```
// First fade
.fadeIn(200, function() {
     $('#table #' + (index + window_left/20)).css({background:'yellow'});
 })
 // ...
 // Second fade
 .fadeIn(200, function() {
      $('#table #' + (index + window_left/20)).css({background:'green'});
 })
```

And in `$("button").click(function () {` right after first `if{}else{}`:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < items + window_left / 20; ++i)
    $('#table #' + (i)).css({background:'#fff'});
```

### 2.

When it comes to the speed you need to convert the value to int:

```
speed = parseInt($("#speed").val());
// Or
speed = +$("#speed").val();
```

Comment: Actually the second fade, it should not go to the fadeIn function; it should go inside last fadeOut. Thanks a lot for your helps!

Comment: @TinaJasmin: Yes, wasn not entirely sure on where you wanted that, but that sounds sound. You could also reset the background inside `animateDivs()` I guess. Depends on how you want it. Glad to help.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with a minor fix. I need to slide the window one step to the right when each ack is received. I don't know why it does not work and nothing changes. Can you help me with that? The updated code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/arianaa30/QhZm3/1/

Comment: @TinaJasmin: Not sure what you mean. You want to move it to the right in its entirety, or also shrink its size by one square for each time? I also can't see anywhere you attempt to do it in the fiddle you linked ...

Comment: After each ack (each cell getting green), the window slides one step. The window size is working now (double up to ssth, and then increments by one).