# DIV animation and property change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to simulate TCP packet transmission and sliding window, and fortunately I've made much progress. But now I want to fix a minor issue with the sliding window, which is a sliding DIV:

Hopefully if you are familiar with TCP's slow start, the window size double up to a number, and then increments by one. This is working. Now what I want to fix is sliding to right. So I want to automatically slide one step right when each ack is received at the original machine. Currently it does not move when the ack is received; so each time I press the button, it retransmits many of the previous packets! My work is here: http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~shossen2/CS438/Project/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    var items = 0;
    var packetNumber = 0;
    var speed = 0;
    var ssth= $("#ssth").val();
    var window_left=0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
        $('#table').append("<div class='inline' id='"+i+"'>"+i+"</div>");
    }
    document.getElementById(1).style.width = 22;

    $("button").click(function() {
        if (items < ssth) {
            if (items == 0)
                items = 1;
            else
                items = items * 2;      
            count++;
        } else {
            items = items + 1;
        }

        window_left += 20;
        window_width=items * 20;

        document.getElementById("window_size").innerHTML = items;
        document.getElementById("window").style.left= window_left + "px";
        document.getElementById("window").style.width=window_width + "px";

        speed = +$("#speed").val();
        createDivs(items);
        animateDivs();
    });

    function createDivs(divs) {
        packetNumber = 1;
        var left = 60;
        for (var i = 0; i < divs; i++) {
            var div = $("<div class='t'></div>");
            div.appendTo(".packets");
            $("<font class='span'>" + (parseInt(packetNumber) + parseInt(window_left/20) -1) + "</font>").appendTo(div);
            packetNumber++;
            div.css({
                left: left
               /* opacity: 0*/
            }).fadeOut(0);

            //div.hide();
            //left += 20;
        }
    }

    function animateDivs() {
        $(".t").each(function (index) {  // added the index parameter
            var packet = $(this);

            packet
                .delay(index * 200)
                .fadeIn(200, function() {
                    $('#table #' + (index + window_left/20)).css({background:'yellow'});
                })
                .animate({left: '+=230px'}, speed)
                .animate({left: '+=230px'}, speed)
                .fadeOut(200, function () {
                    packet
                        .css({
                            top: '+=20px', 
                            backgroundColor: "#f09090"
                        })    
                        .text('a' + packet.text());
                 })                
                .delay(500)
                .fadeIn(200)
                .animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed)
                .animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed)
                .fadeOut(200, function () {

                    packet
                        .css({
                            top: '-=20px',
                            backgroundColor: "#90f090"

                        });
                    $('#table #' + (index + window_left/20)).css({background:'lightgreen'});
                });

            }).promise().done(function(){
                $(".packets").empty();
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Too much code... simplify your problem to increase the number o answers.

Comment: How is this different [from your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770201/div-animation-and-color-change)?

Comment: As Avlaro said, too much code to wade through, but a general note: If you're simulating something, your code should reflect that structure. Right now, all you've got is a series of jquery animations, which is extremely difficult to parse and follow for anyone unfamiliar with the code. It would be a lot easier if you had, say, a function for the "transmit" portion, and perhaps a callback for the "ack" being received. That not only increases comprehensibility, but makes it easier to extend your code in the future if you want to do something besides animate a picture during one of the steps.

Comment: @j08691 The main project is the same; but now I need to change the step of sliding window, which I can not.